# Echoing Correct Time in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have a problem on my computer. From time to time, certain features stop working, for perhaps 1-5 minutes. Ping ceases to work when this occurs. So I thought I'd gather some stats about this issue via a batch file that would run ping perhaps 1000 times and echo the time when it started and then again when it stopped. This is the file:

```
echo off
set i=
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,3) DO (

   echo %time%
   ping www.google.com
   echo %time%
)
```

But what happens is the first time echoed is the same as the second time. WHy? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside a command block (surrounded by `(`parantheses`)`), you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,3) DO (
   echo !time!
   ping www.google.com
   echo !time!
)
```

Comment: You don't need delayed expansion inside all commandblocks, for example redirect command blocks don't need it. Only if and for as far as I am aware.

Comment: It seems you're right, I really thought only the for and if need it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @DennisvanGils Syntax: `if a==a <command>`, where `command` might also be a (block of commands). Doesn't matter, if there is a IF statement  in front of it or not. (same with `for .... do <command>`)